# Wired connection not working, Gnome Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: internet, wired

I am having a problem connecting to the Internet. Using the router in my room I am attaching the output from the ifconfig command as well as the website when I directly type in the address of the router. However, When I try to open a web browser, there is no connection, and any address e.g. google.com is not resolved.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novices but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.